# Running PySide in a background thread crashes on exit

Tags: python, pyside

Here's the code I have:

```
import threading
import time
import sys

from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *

def do_all():
    # global app, wid
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    wid = QWidget()
    wid.setWindowTitle('Simple')
    wid.show()

    app.exec_()
    print "exiting thread"
    time.sleep(1)

t = threading.Thread(target=do_all)
t.start()
t.join()

time.sleep(1)
print "exiting main"
```

This brings up a window, as expected. When I close it, three things happen:

1. The first print executes
2. The second print executes
3. [image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I also see the error message `WARNING: QApplication was not created in the main() thread.`, which may give a hint.

Comment: Another error seen when using `moveToThread` method of the widget ... `Widgets cannot be moved to a new thread`.

Comment: Yep, I saw that warning too, but I read elsewhere that qt should be fine as long as all gui stuff is in the same thread

Comment: @Eric. The warning is telling you that the application must be in the **main** thread (i.e. the one in which the script started), and all gui-related stuff must happen in that thread as well. Create separate threads for workers, and use custom signals to communicate with the main gui thread. (See [Threads, Events, QObjects](https://wiki.qt.io/ThreadsEventsQObjects)).

Comment: @ekhumoro: I'm trying to tack a debug UI onto an existing command line application, so I don't really want the coupling to work in that direction

Comment: @Eric. Well, you've got no choice - that's just the way qt works. So use a separate process, rather than a separate thread, and then communicate with the cli app via a socket (or whatever other ipc solution you prefer).

Comment: I agree with the others that only the main thread should be used for GUI stuff, however, swapping `PySide` for `PyQt4` removes the warning and avoids the crash upon exit (at least for your basic example).